# Notice: Trying to get property '******' of non-object

Tags: php, html

tengo un problema y es que al querer imprimir unos datos, me aparece el error "Notice: Trying to get property 'contenido' of non-object"

Código de la llamada de los datos:

```html
<?php
include_once("config.php");

$sentencia=$db->query("SELECT * FROM posts;");
$posts=$sentencia->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>
```

Aquí es el fragmento donde imprimo los datos:

```html
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <?php include ("datos.php"); ?>
          <?php foreach($posts as $post){?>
            <div class="card mb-3">
                <div class="card-body">

  <?php echo $post->nombre ?>
    <?php echo $post->usersid ?>
      <?php echo $post->tiposid ?>
        <?php echo $post->fecha ?>
          <?php echo $post->contenido ?>
            <?php echo $post->imagen ?>
      
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

La constante `MYSQLI_ASSOC` que estás pasando a `fetch_all()` te devuelve los datos como una matriz (array) asociativa, no como un objeto. Por tanto, no puedes aplicar la sintaxis de lectura de objetos que es: `$objeto->propiedad`, sino la de arrays que es `$array["indice"]`.

Precisamente, lo que indica el mensaje *`Trying to get property 'contenido' of non-object"`*  es que `$post` no es un objeto, sino un array.

Por otra parte, `fetch_all` no ofrece la posibilidad de devolver los resultados como objetos, [según el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php):

> #### resulttype
>
> Este parámetro opcional define mediante una constante qué tipo de array debe producirse a partir de los datos actuales. Los
> valores posibles para este parámetro son las constantes
> `MYSQLI_ASSOC,` `MYSQLI_NUM`, o `MYSQLI_BOTH`.

Si intentas el código de este modo debería funcionar, salvo errores adicionales:

```
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <?php include ("datos.php"); ?>
      <?php foreach($posts as $post){?>
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-body">
```

```
<?php echo $post["usersid"] ?>
  <?php echo $post["tiposid"] ?>
    <?php echo $post["fecha"] ?>
      <?php echo $post["contenido"] ?>
        <?php echo $post["imagen"] ?>
  
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

Simplemente, dado que `$post` debería ser un array, se ha cambiado la forma de lectura de `$post->propiedad` a `$post["indice"]`.

Si no funciona, haz un `var_dump($post);` y muestra un extracto del resultado.